# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated moves views up 20 pixels in original view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a navigation controller within one of the tabs in a tab bar.

Within the nav controller I have the root view.

I am presenting a modal view like this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
```

However, when I dismiss the view with:

```
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

.. the original view gets moved up 20 pixels, so it is under the status bar. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a tab bar, you should present your view from `UITabBarController`, so that your tab's content stays untouched:

```
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];

[self.tabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick thing to check - is the size of the modal view correct (i.e. if set up in interface builder then does it have the right bottom and top bar space set aside). Odd things can happen if not... Ditto with the original view - if it's not the right size in the nib for both the upper navbar and the bottom tabbar then it might go wrong...

Answer (score 0):

for the better development, you should add the size of your modal view. Use CGRect or edit your view on xib file. It may work... :)